# separate compilaton in CUDA

Tags: cuda

System specs: laptop with nvidia optimus support (geforce 740m, supports compute capability 2.0), ubuntu 13.10, cuda 5.0, optirun (Bumblebee) 3.2.1.

Im' trying to compile and run simpler version of example described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#examples):

**main.cu**

```
#include "defines.h"
#include <cuda.h>

int main () 
{
    hello<<<1, 1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

**defines.h**

```
#include <cuda.h>

extern __global__ void hello(void);
```

**defines.cu**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda.h>

__global__ void hello()
{
    printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

using:

```
nvcc –arch=sm_20 –dc main.cu defines.cu
nvcc –arch=sm_20 main.o defines.o
```

When I try to run output **a.out** file using:

```
optirun ./a.out
```

I get no "Hello!" in console. What can be the problem?

Comment: your card has compute capability 3.0, not 2.0. also, are you compiling with code relocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not right:

```
nvcc –arch=sm_20 –dc main.cu defines.cu
nvcc –arch=sm_20 main.cu defines.cu
```

The first command performs compilation (but no linking) in separate compilation mode.
The second command performs compilation and linking in one step, but without using separate compilation mode.

Try just this:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -rdc=true main.cu defines.cu
```

The relevant `nvcc` documentation is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda)

Alternatively, and following the example you linked, you could also do this:

```
nvcc –arch=sm_20 –dc main.cu defines.cu
nvcc –arch=sm_20 main.o defines.o
```

As @JackOLantern points out, you may wish to replace `sm_20` in the above commands with `sm_30` to match your device, but that is not the reason for the failure you are observing.  Code compiled for `-arch=sm_20` will run on a cc 3.0 device.

Comment: Do you wish to mention that the poster's card GeForce 740M has compute capability 3.0?

Comment: Code compiled for `-arch=sm_20` will run on a cc 3.0 device.  That is not an immediate cause of the failure being reported.

Comment: I made an update to post, and what I found out - it works correctly usng both ways of compiling .o files (-dc and -rdc=true) ONLY using right compute capability, in my case it's 3.0,so many thanks to JackOlantem.