# CUDA calling device functions from separate files (Name mangling?)

Tags: c++, cuda

How should I do this properly? Here is a simplification of the code:

```
//main.cu    
#include "math.cuh"

__global__ void test(float *x, unsigned numElements)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < numElements)
    {
        float array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        copyArray(x + 5*i, array, 5);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    test<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, numElements);
}

//math.cuh
__device__ void copyArray(float *dest, float *src, unsigned length);

//math.cu
#include "math.cuh"
__device__ void copyArray(float *dest, float *src, size_t length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }
}
```

compiled with this command:

```
nvcc -rdc=true -arch=sm_20 -o cudaMain main.cu math.cu -Xlinker -framework,OpenGL,-framework,GLUT && ./cudaMain
```

and got this error:

```
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_Z9copyArrayPfS_j' in '/tmp/tmpxft_00000265_00000000-21_main.o'
```

This clearly looks like a name mangling error, but I tried putting extern "C" in all sorts of places and it didn't work.

Comment: What operating system? Are you using make or cmake?

Comment: Please clarify the problem more, what was the error, when did it happen, while linking? What exactly did you do to call the function?

Comment: This seems to be a separate compilation issue. Try compiling with `-rdc=true`. There are many questions on SO facing separate compilation, for example: [separate compilaton in CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381837/separate-compilaton-in-cuda?rq=1).

Comment: Agree with @JackOLantern.  If function is called in `main.cu`, declared in `file.cuh`, and defined in `file.cu`, separate compilation/device code linking is definitely needed.  Jack do you want to provide an answer?  I would upvote.  Or else let's mark as duplicate.  try `nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o main -rdc=true main.cu file.cu`

Comment: The question title seems like it is likely to show up in searches, so an answer here would be useful.

Comment: @khcshadow Your edit made the situation a bit more confused. Could you please provide the minimum sized code reproducing your problem? In this way, someone could try compiling your code and finding the solution.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Robert, let's wait. I would say that, after the edit, the OP should provide some more information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @JackOLantern What other information would be helpful?  I'll reformat the code to be in one block. Hopefully that will make it more clear...

Comment: The function prototype uses `unsigned` while the definition uses `size_t`. Is that the cause?

Comment: @shaoyl85 good call! Was so focused on playing with extern "C" I wasn't even paying attention to that.  Thanks!

Comment: @shaoyl85 Could you please convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function prototype uses `unsigned` while the definition uses `size_t`. Is that the cause?